# How to get the dynamically created label control text from dynamically created stackpanel in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

My purpose is get details of selected items in listview. The image and caption in listview is displayed by using dynamically created stackpanel. Dynamically created image file and caption is added to stackpanel. Now I want to the details of selected items in listview? can any help me to sort it out

```
// dynamically creating stackpanel in listview

 FileStream stream = new FileStream(item.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 Image i = new Image();
 i.Width = 100;
 i.Height = 100;
 i.Margin = new Thickness(15);
 i.ToolTip = item.Name;

 i.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
 BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();

 src.BeginInit();
 src.UriSource = new Uri(SelectedImagePath + "\\" + item.Name);
 src.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
 src.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
 //src.StreamSource = stream;
 src.EndInit();
 i.Source = src;
 Label lb = new Label();
 lb.Width = 110;
 lb.Height = 110;
 lb.Content = item.Name;
 StackPanel pn = new StackPanel();
 pn.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
 pn.Width = 160;
 pn.Height = 160;
 pn.Children.Add(i);
 pn.Children.Add(lb);
 listView1.Items.Add(pn);

// for retrieving the label control text 

 string fname;
 foreach (StackPanel pan in listView1.SelectedItems)
 {
     var lbl = pan.Children[1].ToString();//not getting in correct format
     MessageBox.Show(lbl.ToString());
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up the MVVM Design pattern, you can use an ItemsControl to dynamiclaly create UIELements from a List (or Observable Collection) of Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the `StackPanel.Children` item to it's proper type, instead of calling `ToString()` :

```
var lbl = (Label)pan.Children[1];   //or use index [0] if you meant the 1st child
MessageBox.Show((string)lbl.Content);
```